# Return row number with queryset in Django

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I am working with Django and MongoDb with Django. How can I return a query set with row number in it? I have tried to explore aggregation functions of mongo but could not achieve the result.

```
import uuid
from django import models


class Snippet(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
    body = models.TextField()
```

**Expected output**

```
{
    "id": "a3cee4c9-6e23-4710-81e2-dda67a2b98d5",
    "title": "sad",
    "body": "a sad story",
    "row" : "1"
},
{
    "id": "3e8b054e-aea7-4fa0-9019-3afa1a1efd15",
    "title": "happy",
    "body": "a happy story",
    "row" : "2"
},
{
    "id": "7e8d782e-583f-4f31-96e6-8dc267e69e9f",
    "title": "angry",
    "body": "an angry man",
    "row" : "3"
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add a row field to your model?

Comment: The **expected output** does show data in JSON format. Do you only need the row number in the serialized data? Then you could customize the serialization.

Comment: @cbergmiller Yes. I have a serializers.py. Can you suggest the solution.